# Как организовать структуру базы данных?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Есть БД `users`. В одной из таблиц есть поля `login`, `password`, `id`. Как связать несколько пользователей? Т.е. пользователь с логином `Вася` является другом `Алексея` ? А у пользователя `Петр` есть, например, 14 друзей (`Леша`, `Вася`, `Катя` ..).

Какие нужно делать таблицы? Как организовывать, т.е. как делать между ними связи?

DB - MySQL.

Как структурируются большие объемы данных в БД? Например, как в соц.сетях - пользователь `Олег` имеет хобби 1,2 и 3, участвует в группах номер 32, 43, 65, а также у него есть личные фотографии, видео, аудио.

Что изучить, чтобы понять, как это корректно делается?
Если знаете мануалы по данному вопросу - подскажите, буду благодарен.

Answer (score 2):

Изучите три типа связей:

- один к одному
- один ко многим
- многие ко многим

Информации в сети очень много. Есть примеры и таблиц, и запросов. Вот один из вариантов https://habrahabr.ru/post/193380/

Для хранения графа друзей лучше использовать графовую БД (neo4j). Так как использовать реляционную БД (MySql) для этой цели не так эффективно.